# Opening 2 files with the same Name but different directories

Tags: excel, vba

I have written a macro which opens 2 comma delimited files (Generic Tables used by Prophet 8.1 ending with a .fac extension), does a comparison and creates another workbook which highlights all the differences.

The macro seems to fail when the files have the same name but has different directories.

What would be the easiest way to overcome this problem without having to actually change the file name as seen in the location? It is against company policy to mess with the actual files as seen in the location. Is there a way to assign some temporary name to the file and not save it?

Answer (score 2):

In Excel you cannot have two files open with the same name!

If you don't want to rename the files, copy one temporarily using a different name - and delete it afterwards (assuming you only want to read from it)

If you have to modify/save the original files, then the only two options you have is to rename them (you can afterwards rename them back to the original name) - or change your procedure so only one file is open at the time (e.g. by temporarily storing some data from the first file in a temp workbook that gets created and closed during the code execution).